# proofing the $ \nabla (FG) $

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$\\ F $and$ G$  are vector fields

my problem is that why the answer is not $ (\nabla. F)G + (\nabla .G)F $

Comment: Are you sure $F$ and $G$ are both vector fields? In that case by $FG$ you either mean $F\cdot G$ or $FG^T$ (the outer product) and similarly for the other terms in your equation.

Comment: You can use the "\cdot" LaTeX command. For example: $\nabla \cdot G$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from above, if $F, G$ are indeed vector fields in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then write them out accordingly, viz;

$$ F = F_{1}\hat{i} + F_{2}\hat{j} + F_{3}\hat{k}$$

And apply on this vector (respectively $G$)

$$\nabla = \sum_{p=1}^{3}e^{p}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{p}}$$

Where the $e_{p}$'s represent the standard $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ basis written slightly differently above.

Comment: my problem is that why the answer is not $ (\nabla. F)G + (\nabla .G)F $

Comment: I wonder if you are confused as to the nature of $F$ and $G$, if $F$ and $G$ were scalar fields then the product rule would be in operation here and you would see the $\nabla$ version of it. If $F$ and $G$ are vector fields then here you may be seeing the gradient vector dot product.

Comment: do u agree that $ FG = GF$ so the $ \nabla (FG)= \nabla(GF)$ but if we turn the F and G  and calculate  $ \nabla(GF)$ the answer is not equal to $\nabla(FG)$!.is it?

Comment: Check @Dan's comment above Jack, if these are vector fields, then $FG$ means $FG^{T}$ and as such (wlog) $FG \neq GF$

Answer (score 0):

because

(fg)'|x = f'g|x + fg'|x

(fg)'|y = f'g|y + fg'|y

(fg)'|z = f'g|z + fg'|z

so

∇(FG)=F(∇.G)+G.(∇F)